# reset the data in the table of data set in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, dataset

im populating the data in the combo box using dataset tables...with some table name..now i want to clear those entries or data populated in the combobox every time when the button is clicked...so that new entries can be done.... is there any way to clear the comobo box values??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combobox1.datasource = null;
combobox1.items.clear();
```

Comment: THANKS FOR UR ANS BUT comboBox1.Datasource=null; '==' is for comparison purpose..correct ur code..